Win11 Firewall how to limit outbound traffic to specific WAN/LAN servers/PCs
I got conflicting advice from ChatGPT, so I thought I'd ask humans instead.
I have a couple of apps (.exe and java) which I need to limit outgoing connections/responses to only
(1) a specified internet server or two
(2) responses to incoming http(s) connections only from other PCs on my LAN, including 127.0.0.1 (I already have an allow-all incoming traffic rule from my LAN PCs)
(3) and block everything else outgoing from these apps to any other servers (all ports).
In Windows 11 Firewall, I gather it could be possible to be done in a single Outbound Rule ?
"Fighting" with ChatGPT I received several totally conflicting answers so I gave up with it and am 100% confused, eg which rules somehow took precedence and how blocks and allows applied within and across rules.
Advice would be very greatly appreciated on how to implement the rule(s) to do as described above.

You can configure Windows Firewall to block all outgoing traffic by default and selectively allow specific outbound connections, press Win + R and type wf. MSc, press Enter to open Windows Firewall with Advanced Security, click Outbound Rules, create a new outbound rule to block all traffic (choose Block as the action), and then create additional rules to allow specific URLs or IP addresses (choose Allow as the action). Ensure the rules are ordered correctly (block first, allow later).

I guess I add those rules for each program ?  One of the things ChatGPT told me was the the first matching rule (here it would be block) would be applied and that's it ... go figure.  So, if I interpret it properly, you're saying that for the nominated program create a series of outbound rules which are applied in the order they are created.  OK.
In the gui, I see the list of rules and the order of display is by clicking on the column heading - is there some way of showing the rules in the proper order of creation so that one can see the order they are applied ?  Thanks.

Also, is there a way to export selected rule(s) to be imported on another PC ?  Again, ChatGPT told me yes but there's no menu items I could readily find to do that.
